# Print parallel progress bars for subprocesses in python map_async

Tags: python-3.x, locking, python-multiprocessing, tqdm

I have a list of pandas dataframe. I want to run a python function on each dataframe on all of my cores in parallel. My function looks like this:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

def f(df):
    for _, row in tqdm(df.iterrows, total=len(df)):
        # Do some processing
    
    return result


list_of_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3, df3]
ncores = 4
pool = Pool(ncores)
results = pool.map_async(f, list_of_dataframes)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However, I'm not seeing four progress bars updating parallel in the output from each chile process. I see only one bar getting updated and that too moves back and forth. For example, it moves till 5% and then again moves back to 2%. I believe that this is due to all processes updating the same bar.

I tried keeping a global progress bar and updating it inside each function call like this, but this isn't working.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm 
from multiprocessing import Pool

list_of_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
total_rows = len(df1) + len(df2) + len(df3) + len(df4)

def f(df):
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        # Some processing
        pbar.update(1)
    return 1 

with tqdm(total=total_rows) as pbar: 
    list_of_dataframes = [df1, df2, df3, df3]
    ncores = 4
    pool = Pool(ncores)
    results = pool.map_async(f, list_of_dataframes)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

But this is also not working. The progress bar is behaving similarly. Is there any way to put lock on pbar variable in the code above so that only one process can update the progress bar at once, or any way to show 4 progress bars in parallel?

Comment: if using `multiprocessing` they will be separate instances. You would need to use `Value` to make the variable common between processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do what you need with a small [parallelbar](https://github.com/dubovikmaster/parallelbar) library.

for example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from parallelbar import progres_map


def foo(df):
    for row in df.iterrows():
        #do something
        pass
    return 'done'

if __name__=='__main__':
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 5)))
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 5)))
    df_3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 5)))
    df_4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000, 5)))
    result = progress_map(foo, [df_1, df_2, df_3, df4])
```

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dubovikmaster/parallelbar/main/gifs/first_bar_.gif]

You can also find more details [here](https://medium.com/pythoneers/visualize-your-multiprocessing-calculations-in-python-with-parallelbar-5395651f35aa)